# XmlNamespaceManager.AddNameSpace behaves correctly on local machine but not server

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, xml-namespaces

I've written some code to read the contents from Word .dotx files. On my development machine all is fine and the document contents can be read but on the server the code causes a large increase in CPU usage and the documents are not read (for an unknown reason).

Sample XML taken from a Word .dotx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" 
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" 
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" 
mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="00276253" 
w:rsidRDefault="00276253"><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Header"/>
</w:pPr></w:p><w:p......
```

My method:

```
public static string TextFromWordXMLFile(string path){
  StringBuilder stringBuilder;    
  try {
       using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = 
              WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false)) {
                NameTable nameTable = new NameTable();
                XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager =
                  new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
                xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace(
                  "w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

       string wordprocessingDocumentText;
       using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(wordprocessingDocument
             .MainDocumentPart.GetStream())){
         wordprocessingDocumentText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
       }

       stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(wordprocessingDocumentText.Length);
       XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument(nameTable);
       xmlDocument.LoadXml(wordprocessingDocumentText);
       XmlNodeList paragraphNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//w:p", 
                                    xmlNamespaceManager);
       foreach (XmlNode paragraphNode in paragraphNodes) {
         XmlNodeList textNodes = paragraphNode.SelectNodes(".//w:t | .//w:tab | .//w:br",
                                 xmlNamespaceManager);
         foreach (XmlNode textNode in textNodes) {
           switch (textNode.Name) {
             case "w:t":
               stringBuilder.Append(textNode.InnerText);
               break;
             case "w:tab":
               stringBuilder.Append("\t");
               break;
             case "w:br":
               stringBuilder.Append("\v");
               break;
           }
         }
         stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
         if (stringBuilder.Length > Length) break;
       }
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
  } catch (IOException) {
     // This is likely to be that the file is in use because 
     // we're currently already opening it in word: ignore.
  }    
  return "";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm  pretty stuck on this one...

Thanks,

Ryan.

Comment: Please do not use the comment section to post code. Stackoverflow has the tools to mark your code. Take some time to get familiar with the tools to avoid posting messy questions. Thanks :)